# Is it possible to hide properties?

Tags: javascript, object, oop, this, console.log

I'm trying to recreate a Set object in JS, and I've got it figured out. I'm just wondering if it is possible to hide an object's property. I don't think there is so I wanted to ask.

This is the problem:

/*
Declare a function, 'Collection', which takes in an array as an argument and returns an instance of a 'Collection' object when invoked with the 'new' keyword.
'Collection' objects should function similarly to a Set - i.e., they will store UNIQUE values (no duplicates) inside where its values and keys are the same.
All Collection objects should contain their own 'size' property, which keeps track of the number of items they contain. When a Collection is first created, it should have a size of 0.
*/

This is what I initially had:

```
function Collection (arr) {
  // size property initialized to 0
  this.size = 0;
  // cache property to store unique arr elements
  this.cache = {}

  // loop thru input arr
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // if the current arr element is not a key in the cache prop, create a key/val pair 
    if (!this.cache[arr[i]]) {
      // key and value are the same
      this.cache[arr[i]] = arr[i];
      // increment the size prop
      this.size ++;
    };
  };
}
```

```
const testObj = new Collection([1, 2, 2, 3, true, true, 'hi', 'hi'])
console.log(testObj.cache); // {'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, 'true': true, 'hi': 'hi'}
console.log(testObj.size); // -> 5
```

I created an object as a property because I wanted to be able to log an object to the console without the size property. But I thought that it would be better to not declare an object as a property.

Which led me to my second solution. But this shows the size property when I console log it.

```
function Collection (arr) {
  // size property initialized to 0
  this.size = 0;

  // loop thru input arr
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // if the current arr element is not a key in the cache prop, create a key/val pair 
    if (!this[arr[i]]) {
      // key and value are the same
      this[arr[i]] = arr[i];
      // increment the size prop
      this.size ++;
    };
  };
}
```

```
// const testObj = new Collection([1, 2, 2, 3, true, true, 'hi', 'hi'])
// console.log(testObj); // {'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, size: 5, 'true': true, 'hi': 'hi'}
// console.log(testObj.size); // -> 5
```

Comment: getter/setter might work

Comment: `But this shows the size property when I console log it` as does the first code

Comment: See [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Comment: The fact that whatever is asking you this question says that `Collection` should be invoked with new suggests the fact that you should create a class (instead of a function constructor). You can define private properties in a class with `this.#propertyname`.

Comment: JavaScript classes now have [private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) too... But if you keep working with functions, you can also just create a local variable in it.

Comment: if you want to "recreate" `Set`, since `size` is output when you console log a `Set`, why do you see an issue? also, all object properties are accessible when logged to the console, so you're fighting a losing battle

Comment: and what about this kind of entries ? `const testObj = new Collection([1, 2, '2', 3, true, 'true', 'hi', 'hi'])`

Comment: @MisterJojo what do you mean

Comment: in a  real `Set` `2` and `"2"` are not the same element, but not in yours, idem for `true`...

Comment: @MisterJojo I see what you mean now, I managed to fix that by changing my cache from an obj to an arr

Comment: there is no array in any of your sample code

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom Collection class, instead of making a function, that acts in the same way.

```
class Collection {
  cache = []
  size = 0
  constructor(list) {
    this.addAll(list)
  }

  contains(item) {
    return(this.cache.includes(item))
  }

  add(item) { // Add single item
    if (!this.contains(item)) { // Check for duplicates
      this.cache.push(item) // Add item
      this.size ++ // Increment size
      return(true) // Return true if added
    }
    return(false) // Return false if already exists
  }

  addAll(list) {
    for (element of list) { // Loop through each element
      this.add(element) // Use the singular add method to add the item
    }
  }
}
```

After you have the class and any methods you need, all you need to do is create your new Collection object and output the cache:

```
test = new Collection([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
console.log(test.cache)
```

If you don't want to have to have `test.cache`, you can utilize your own `toString` method instead, but you will still have to output `test.toString()`.

If you're looking to be able to run `console.log(test)` and have it not print the size, you're out of luck.

Comment: ah ok thats what I figured, thanks for the insight with creating a class though